# Is there a 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' for another query

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I know `SHOW CREATE TABLE` gives you the script in order to create a table based on an existing table but I would like to get the script for the return of a *query*.

*Example* : I have lots of really long and complex queries, but now I would like to create tables for what these queries fetch.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just create the tables? With or without the data?

Comment: Have you considered views instead?

Comment: What's your end goal here?  You could do something like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS YourQuery` then `SHOW CREATE TABLE temp_table`, but it begs the question if you just want to create a permanent table out of the results in the first place..

Comment: @AaronDietz I just want the script to create a table somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the creation script, you can put the results of your query into a temporary table, then use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE query1 AS
    SELECT * FROM YourQuery
    LIMIT 0; --Add LIMIT 0 to avoid putting all the data into the table TY Bill Karwin

SHOW CREATE TABLE query1;
```

If you can access the end destination for the table (and you want the results included), you can skip a step and just use `CREATE..SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE permanent1 AS
    SELECT * FROM YourQuery;
```

Comment: Good answer, but one might want to use `LIMIT 0` if all one needs is the table definition. That will avoid the table filling up with data from the SELECT.